# finding all possible. numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integers

When a number is divided by $11$,the obtained number equals the sum of the squares of the digits of the starting number. If the starting number has three digits, find all such numbers.

Detailed solution please.

Comment: What have you tried?  If all else fails, a brute force search isn't too bad.

Answer (score 0):

> Not a 'real' answer, but it was too big for a comment. I think that you're looking for a solution without using a calculator or PC but maybe this gives some insight.

I wrote and ran some [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica)-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
ParallelTable[
  If[TrueQ[IntegerQ[n/11] && 
     n/11 == (Last@IntegerDigits[n])^2 + (Part[IntegerDigits[n], 
          1 + Floor[Log10[n]] - 1])^2 + (Part[IntegerDigits[n], 
          1 + Floor[Log10[n]] - 2])^2], n, Nothing], {n, 100, 
   999}] //. {} -> Nothing
```

Running the code gives:

```
Out[1]={550, 803}
```

This is true, because:

- $$\frac{550}{11}=50=5^2+5^2+0^2\tag1$$
- $$\frac{803}{11}=73=8^2+0^2+3^2\tag2$$

Comment: Why would you write a code so obfuscated?
Cases[Range[1000], n_ /; n/11 == Total[IntegerDigits[n]^2]]
does the job.

Comment: @jjagmath Because if you want to expand my code, it is not hard to understand how my code works.

Comment: I understand your code, but why to give an obscure answer?

Comment: @jjagmath You're a good Mathematica programmer, I am not that good at programming.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can utilize the fact that $11 | \overline{abc} \implies 11 | (a-b+c)$

Since $-8 = 1-9+0\le a-b+c\le 9-0+9 = 18$, either $a-b+c=0$ or $a-b+c=11$.

**Case 1:** $a+b-c=0 \implies a^2+(a+c)^2+c^2 = (100a+10b+c)/11\\=(100a+10(a+c)+c)/11=10a+c \\\implies 2a^2+(2c-10)a+2c^2-c=0\\
\implies \Delta = (2c-10)^2 -  8(2c^2-c) \ge 0\\
\implies 3c^2+8c-25 \le 0 \implies c \le (\sqrt{91}-4)/3 < 2$

Because $c$ is even, then $c=0, a=5, b=5, \overline{abc}=550.$

**Case 2:** $a+b-c=11 \implies a^2+(a+c-11)^2+c^2 = (100a+10b+c)/11\\=(100a+10(a+c-11)+c)/11=10a+c-10 \\\implies 2a^2+(2c-32)a+2c^2-23c+131=0\\
\implies \Delta = (2c-32)^2 - 8(2c^2-23c+131) \ge 0\\
\implies 3c^2-14c+6 \le 0 \implies c \le (\sqrt{31}+7)/3 < 5$

Because $c$ is odd, $c=1$ (no integer solution) or $c=3, a=8, b=0, \overline{abc}=803.$